# WSO2 EI 6.4.0 Docker Container -javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null

Tags: docker, ssl, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

There is an implementation where `API-1` is calling another `API-2`, Both are deployed in same WSO2 docker container 6.4.0.

Internal API Call is not working, Got below ERROR in logs.

```
Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://integ.company.com/wso2/api/queue_service]
    javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:194)
```

In the background, There is some SSL Certificate renewal activity happened at HA Proxy level, Post this we started to get above ERROR.

Can I get some suggestion to resolve this ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the certificate used for 'https://integ.company.com/wso2/api/queue_service' to WSO2 servers client-trustore. If that doesn't resolve the issue add the full Stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Hi @ycr,
The above mentioned service (https://integ.company.com/wso2/api/queue_service) is also wso2 service which also deployed in same container. 2 different services/APIs deployed in same container. then importing certificate to the same container may  not needed right since both are deployed in same wso2 container. Kindly correct me if my understanding is incorrect

Comment: @Justin you need to have the public cert in the ClientTrustore anyway. It doesn't matter if you are calling the same server. For an SSL handshake to work the certs need to be in pace.

Comment: SSL renewal done at HA Proxy level, do i need to import SSL certificate of HA proxy into wso2 container? or how can i achieve this, Kindly suggest me

Comment: This depends on where the DNS `integ.company.com` resolves to. If t resolves to HA proxy, if yes you have to import HAProxy certs.